# Has anyone successfully deleted a Google Cloud Git repository and subsequently created a new one?

Tags: git, repository, google-cloud-platform

According to Google's Cloud Platform documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-deleting) you should be able to delete a source code repository and have a new one automatically re-created.  But after I deleted a repository for a project the web page returns with "Failed to load" message. Now I am no longer able to see a repository for the project nor can I use Android Studio to access any repository at that project. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Delete with caution!

Answer (score 1):

Using my google.com ID I used 'git push origin master' to push a single commit to an empty repo, deleted the repo using the Web UI.  (That's where you have to echo back the project name to be really really sure you want to delete).  The next thing I saw was a page "Your Cloud Repository is empty".  Then I just went back to the command line and issued 'git push origin master' again.  The repo was fine.

In my experience, 'Failed to load' is some failure unrelated to repo operations.  Reloading the page may just fix it.

Comment: Thanks John, but I don't recall seeing the "Your Cloud Repository is empty" message... all I got was a "Failed to load" message. Reloading the page has no effect (even used a different fresh browser). I sent you an email with a screen shot of the error.

Comment: Thanks Ron. From the screenshot I was able to find two bugs: 1) The problem is not reported correctly, resulting in 'Failed to load' rather than an actionable message. I will fix that.  2) The underlying repo system has a problem we are investigating. It may be related to a shift in how projects (and thus there default repositories) are named.

Comment: Our fix for issue #2 has landed, I hope you are successful now.

Comment: Yep, it's working as it should now. Thanks John for looking into the issue and correcting it. All is good again.